# Type union and intersection when used in conjunction

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I started learning TypeScript recently and a bit confused with a type intersection/union concept. In the following code snippet, I assume the compiler should warn error about the absent of parameter `z`, but it wouldn't.

```
interface DataA { x: string, y: string, z: string }
interface DataB { x: string }
interface A { id: string, data: DataA }
interface B { id: string, data: DataB }

type C = A & B
type D = B
type X = C | D

function bar(val: X) {}

bar({
  id: "some id",
  data: {
    x: "some data",    
    y: "some data"
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why you would assume that the compiler would complain about the missing `z`?  The value you pass to `var` is a valid `B`, which is assignable to `X = B | C`.  If anything it might complain about the extra `y`, but [properties of non-discriminated unions present in at least one member do not trigger excess property warnings](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863).  If you can explain your thinking process, I might be able to explain where it differs from what the compiler is doing.  Good luck.

Comment: My assumption was that either x, y and z should be present or only x. Thus it would correspond to either A or A&B, but not something in between. Thanks for link, it is seems to be directly related to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type X = C | D  =  (A & B) | B` and since `A & B` is a more strict version of `B`, so the least requirement of type `X` is `B`, your assigning data satisfy all the required field of `B` and even have additional field of `y` compared to `B`, so it's assignable to `X`